# What is the meaning of the parameter epsilon in SVM?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, svm, weka

I am using weka for classification and I would like to understand what does it mean to change the value of epsilon in SVM Classifier.

Comment: i dont know weka but python has an equivalent function for epsilon SVM and called SVR (sklearn.svm.SVR).  read this: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/259018/meaning-of-epsilon-in-svm-regression

Answer (score 0):

The tooltip says:

epsilon -- The epsilon for round-off error (shouldn't be changed).

Take a look at

https://svn.cms.waikato.ac.nz/svn/weka/trunk/weka/src/main/java/weka/classifiers/functions/SMO.java

m_eps is used in a method called takeStep(). Here is the definition:

```
   /**
     * Method solving for the Lagrange multipliers for
     * two instances.
     *
     * @param i1 index of the first instance
     * @param i2 index of the second instance
     * @param F2
     * @return true if multipliers could be found
     * @throws Exception if something goes wrong
     */
    protected boolean takeStep(int i1, int i2, double F2) throws Exception {
```